# existence of a simple function

Tags: real-analysis

For an integrable function $f$ over $E$, is there always a simple function $\phi$ so that $$\int_E |f - \phi|$$ can be as small as you wish?

I got this from my old notes from two years back. My hunch, now, is that we can find such a function but it depends on how small we want our integral to be. I never got around to do answer this problem then. Now, I'm lost on how to go about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

- Reduce to the case where $f\geqslant 0$ writing $f=f^+-f^-$, where $f^+:=\max\{0,f\}$ and $f^-:=f^+-f$.
- Use the definition of Lebesgue integral.